# Running tracert through python on windows just keeps going

Tags: python

i have the following script that runs tracert through a python script and it works kind of, like it will print out all the results fine. But then after the last hop it just keeps printing out blank lines, not sure what i am doing wrong here, if anyone can please help me out.

Below is the script that i have

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hostname = "1.1.1.154"
p = Popen("cmd /c tracert " + hostname, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(str(line, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Hint: What determines when it should stop?

Comment: To be honest, i thought it would stop as soon as the traceroute completed

Comment: How would your script know that the traceroute has completed?

Comment: You're using Python 3, right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iter` will keep going until `p.stdout.readline` returns an empty **string**, but `p.stdout.readline` returns an empty **bytes object**.

However, you don't need to use `iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')`. There's a better option: set the encoding when calling `Popen`, and iterate over `p.stdout` since it's a file-like object.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hostname = "1.1.1.154"
p = Popen("cmd /c tracert " + hostname, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

BTW use `str.rstrip('\n')` to remove trailing newlines.